# html table column resize implementation in angular

Tags: html, angular

I have used plain html table and created angular directive for resizing the table colums, but my example is not working as expected like ag-grid resize functionality, any suggestions or inputs are welcome

[my example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resizable-columns-pn3qha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[ag-grid example](https://www.ag-grid.com/examples/column-sizing/column-sizing-to-fit/packages/vanilla/index.html)

my example is working as shown below
[image]

Probelem: When we move fate column towards right side then all other colums are resizing instead of apprearing with scroll after resize

expect behaviour: Scroll bar should come if column size goes beyon view port
[image]

Comment: please include code, not just links and be specific for what's not working, actual vs expected

Comment: If you want to have scrolling, you need to add a container around the table which is set to a fixed width (i.e. 1000px) and has overflow of hidden. Then, when you resize the columns, the table will increase in width because its width is not set, and it has room to expand (overflow is scroll, so indefinitely).